# how to make the category field smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I am a beginner in Amcharts and this is my working code pen [demo](https://codepen.io/RKR001/pen/QGoxbW)

Here I have kept the

`"categoryField": "country"`

to draw the column chart.As you see I have the big names of the countries and they overlap each other.Is there a way to set the font of these to smaller size in Amcharts?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there is nothing in your demo, some invisible lines may be :)

Comment: on my screen they don't overlap

Comment: same here, they look fine.

Comment: @madalin ivascu I am sorry.I updated the link.Could you check now please?

Comment: @Deep I updated the link Could you check it now?

Comment: @Faiz99 I updated the link.Can u check now?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the goal is to display the labels properly

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20,
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
```

Pen :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWRKLy

or if you want to decrease font size only.

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20,
    "fontSize" : 6
  },
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zobaKz

But i will suggest go for the first one

To know more about all the available properties, methods of categoryAxis

https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis

Answer (score 0):

Add the "autowrap" to your "categoryAxis" to avoid the countries name overlap each other.

```
"categoryAxis": {
   "gridPosition": "start",
   "gridAlpha": 0,
   "tickPosition": "start",
   "tickLength": 20,
   "autoWrap": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/auto-wrap-long-category-axis-labels/ This is the option to wrap the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for this purpose and can write your own css for different screens. Check updated code

```
[https://codepen.io/junaid_jedi/pen/yVwEeO]
```

You can change it according to your requirement.